# What happened before the big bang?

Tags: space

Was there space before big bang? Or who knows there might be different heavenly bodies that we might not perceive?

Comment: This question has already been addressed several times.

Comment: No there is no answer anywhere on this site.

Comment: @user979, See physics.SE there are [better answers](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/10389) there.

Answer (score 2):

"What happened before the Big Bang" is like asking what Alexander the Great's phone number was. It's a nonsensical question.

Space and time began with the Big Bang. "When" and "where" began with the Big Bang.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this questions turns out to be a **"yes"**. The big bang is a sudden rapid expansion of space, so yes, there was space before the big bang. To understand more, check this vulgarization [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3MWRvLndzs) by MinutePhysics who corrects some misconceptions about the BB, since you seem to not know the Friedmann-Walker-Robertson-Lemaître metric.